# neat gem not installed correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bourbon, neat

i'm having trouble installing the bourbon `neat` gem in a rails project. When I follow the installation instructions below, it installs neat in `c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neat-1.5.1` but it doesn't add a `neat` folder in the working directory of my rails project. So `@import 'neat'` doesn't work. Neat only works when I copy and paste the folder `c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neat-1.5.1` into my working directory.

### Installation steps for Ruby on Rails:

```
Add Neat to your Gemfile:

gem 'neat'
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

If you see the error Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass", run:

```
bundle update sass
```

Import Neat in your application.css.scss, after Bourbon:

```
@import "bourbon";
@import "neat";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See installation steps at https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat#installation

You are missing step 3:

3. Install the Neat library into the current directory:

   bourbon install # if not already installed

   neat install

Comment: thanks for the info.. that seems to work. i guess what was confusing me was that step 3 is part of the  non-rails install directions.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.. from what I gathered from the Rails install instructions as well was that the Gem is all that's required. Adding the Neat and Bourbon folders in to the project seems counter-intuitive within Rails.